# Content modification date of an file in Cocoa

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, file, nsfilemanager

How can I find out when a file was last time modified in Cocoa?

I tried using NSFileModificationDate attribute of an NSFile but the modification date gets update when you read a file. I just want to know when it was last time changed like in the Mac OS X Finder.

Answer (score 1):

You can try next code:

```
NSDate *fileModificationDate = nil;  
[fileUrl getResourceValue:&fileModificationDate forKey:NSURLContentModificationDateKey error:nil];
NSLog(@"modification date %@", fileModificationDate)
```

You can see the resource keys in NSURL.h  - NSURLContentModificationDateKey and other.
Hope it will help.